# How to turn off Eclipse auto expands JRE classes from Package Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, navigation, package-explorer

Since few weeks, I observe a bug (or unwanted feature) in my Eclipse workspace : when I press 'F3' ('Open Declaration') on a Java Runtime class, it updates the Package Explorer view. Previously, the Package Explorer view was only updating when opening declaration of my own classes located in the project. Now its expands the huge hierarchical tree of JRE classes which is really painful (for instance "Project name" > "JRE System Library" > "rt.jar" > "java.io.PrintWriter"). So the Package Explorer slider becomes unusable to browse through my project.

If I uncheck "Link with Editor", the Package Explorer will no more updates even with my project classes.

How can I restaure the previous behavior : just disabling the link or auto-expand for external libraries and JRE lib ?

I'm using "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers", Photon 4.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Package Explorer:

1. Select the white triangle (View Menu) in the tab's action bar.
2. Select `Filters...`
3. Check `Libraries from external`

The libraries will not appear in the Package Explorer, but their declaration will still be available through the "Open Declaration" command.